# OpenGov submission deposit refund on TimedOut

Tags: opengov

I was curious to know why the submission deposit for an OpenGov proposal is non-refundable if the proposal times out.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/referenda/src/types.rs#L261-L270

```rust
pub fn take_submission_deposit(&mut self) -> Result<Option<Deposit<AccountId, Balance>>, ()> {
    use ReferendumInfo::*;
    match self {
        // Deposit can only be refunded if the proposal is approved or canceled.
        Approved(_, s, _) | Cancelled(_, s, _) => Ok(s.take()),
        // Deposit cannot be refunded if the proposal is ongoing as this would break assumptions.
        Ongoing(..) | Rejected(..) | TimedOut(..) | Killed(..) => Err(()),
    }
}
```

I understand the need to deter spam proposals from going on-chain. Therefore, it makes sense to throw an error on `Rejected` or `Killed` proposals. However, I'm uncertain about `TimedOut` in this context.

For example, consider a scenario where a proposal is wrongly constructed without any intention to spam the chain. In this case, the proposal could be marked as `Rejected` because people vote against it in favor of another one. Unfortunately, I understand that the submission deposit is not refunded in this case.

But if the proposer genuinely puts forth a new proposal without the wrong one progressing to a vote, it will likely end up `TimedOut`. Wouldn't locking the deposit for 14 days serve as a sufficient penalty to deter such spam?

What do you think?